How do I add new elements to an annonymous function array in MatLab?
I need to be able to store a number of functions in an array however the functions are created in a forloop which makes this difficult.
I looked on the help center and you can create a function array of a set size as follows:
f = {@(x)x.^2;
     @(y)y+10;
     @(x,y)x.^2+y+10};

However I want to add them one at a time using a for loop and work for any value of n
so I tried using cells:
n = 6
C = cell(n, 1)
for k = 1:n
   C(k) = @(x) x + n
end

but it returns the error:
"Conversion to cell from function_handle is not possible."
Is there any other way to do this?

Use C{k} instead of C(n)

Also, there is no such thing as anonymous function array. What you are mentioning is cell array of anonymous functions.

ah yes small typo, still the same error is present

“The same error is present”. Sardar’s solution is correct. If it doesn’t work, [edit] your post with the new code, so we can see what error is in that code. Make sure you copy-paste the actual code you are using, and that the code reproduces the error when run in a fresh MATLAB environment, see [mre].

I have confirmed that my code matches my post, I updated it again to be sure. It still produces the same error

I see I missed the {} sorry that was my bad. It works now

1.-
The way to avoid the error mentioned in this question is as explained in the comments:
Index the cell containing the functions with curly brackets { }
n=3
C={}
for k=1:1:n
    
C{k}=@(x) x+n;

end

In MATLAB
f={@(x) x.^2;@(y) y+10;@(x,y) x.^2+y+10}

f(1)

as f defined here f(1) does not run function f but returns content only
 =
  1×1 cell array
    {@(x)x.^2}

To run f function combine { } to call a specific function inside f and ( ) to input values
f{3}(1,2)

f{1}(2)

 =
    13
 =
     4

2.-
Another way is to defined the function in  separate file or at the end of script
fun1=@name_fun;

x=[1 2]
n=10

fun1(x,n)

function F=name_fun(x,n)

F(1)=x(1).^2;
F(2)=x(2)+n;
F(3)= x(1).^2+x(2)+n;

end

3. Using handle to function
This option may be the preferred choice.
When defining a haindle to a function there's no need to use cells :
f1=@(x) x.^2;
s=functions(f1)

So far f1 contains x.^2 only
s is the handle to function f1
s
s = 
  struct with fields:
            function: '@(x)x.^2'
                type: 'anonymous'
                file: ''
           workspace: {[1×1 struct]}
    within_file_path: ''

to add functions to function structure f1
s(2).function=@(x) x+10;
s(3).function=@(x,y) x.^2+y+10;

now the structure s for (vector) function f1 contains 3 functions
s
s = 
  1×3 struct array with fields:
    function
    type
    file
    workspace
    within_file_path
    funciton

Equivalently, directly adding functions to structure:
g.a=@(x) x.^2
g = 
  struct with fields:

    a: @(x)x.^2

adding 2nd function
g.b=@(x) x+10
g = 
  struct with fields:

    a: @(x)x.^2
    b: @(x)x+10

adding 3rd function
g.c=@(x,y) x.^2+y+10
g = 
  struct with fields:

    a: @(x)x.^2
    b: @(x)x+10
    c: @(x,y)x.^2+y+10

using these functions
g.a(3)
 =
   9

g.c(2.1,3.4)
 =
  17.81

